# How to fix a compile error with this code?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the link to the tutorial
https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/excel-vba-send-email-with-attachment/

```
Sub AttachMultipleFilesToEmail()
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

For i = 2 To 5
  source_file = "C:\Work Files\" & Cells(i, 3)
  myMail.Attachments.Add source_file
Next i
End Sub
```

[Where the error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrpGO.png)

[The error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTInw.png)

This is the big picture of what I am trying to do. [Got this image from https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/excel-vba-send-email-with-attachment/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtsp.png) but the files and directory exist and correct. What could be the problem?

Comment: I've revised my answer, in light of your edited question. I think this will fix your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say that you don't have a reference to the outlook dll.

Try clicking on the Tools menu in the VBA editor, and selecting References...

Then scroll down the list until you find `Microsoft Outlook XX Object Library`, and select it.  XX is just the version number.

For future questions, please always tell us the line of code where the error occurs, and the exact error message. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Regarding your revised question:

I ran your code and it works fine. I did however make sure to have the sheet with the filenames as the active sheet, otherwise you will get errors.

I suggest you explictly reference the sheet with the data, rather than just use `Cells(i,3)` as that is shorthand for using the active sheet.

Here is one way to do it:

```
Sub AttachMultipleFilesToEmail()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim myMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim sheet As Worksheet 'declare an object to point to the sheet with the data

    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set myMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set sheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set the object to the correct sheet

    For i = 1 To 2
        source_file = "C:\Work Files\" & sheet.Cells(i, 3) 'use the sheet object to ensure the correct cells are used.
        myMail.Attachments.Add source_file
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help

Comment: I did that but for some reason, my reputation is not enough to do show it on public. And yes, you comment is the right solution. Thank you again.

Comment: This is what it said when I tried to vote for your answer. 

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: I updated the case. Can you maybe help me figure out why the file path is the problem. I am pretty sure I entered the right file path and files.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a reference (Tools-->Reference) and change the "ThisWorbook" to "ActiveWorkoob".  `ThisWorkbook` is not going to work if you are runnign your macro from your Personal module.

[image]